# How to wrap an asp.net WebApi project with azure API management?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps

I am having a Web API project in asp.net and this project is hosted on Azure web app services .Azure endpoint of the api works . How can i wrap this api under azure api management ?

Current setup

Asp.net web Api project  >  Hosted in azure web app services

I tried to add the api in API management via blank and open api specification.

I would expect the Azure API Management could connect to my web app service where my asp.net web api project is hosted.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy your Web API to Azure `App Service API App` instead of `App Service Web App`. You will be able to import the API's directly from the UI. [Here is the doc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/import-api-app-as-api)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to Ketan's approach is to configure API manually using "Blank API" option. where you'll need to specify your App's base URL. You will be required later on to create all operations manually.